# Grouping non-numeric/time categories in PivotTables?

Tags: pivot-table, microsoft-excel-2016

PivotTables in Excel for Mac allowed me to group text (say, countries, like [this](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/images/group-pivot-table-items/two-groups.png)), aggregating the corresponding numeric data (like [this](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/images/group-pivot-table-items/collapsed-groups.png)). I was able to do that following the same process on [this site](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/group-pivot-table-items.html).

When I try to do that in Excel 2016 (Windows), I get a "Cannot group selection." From what I've found on [MS site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Group-or-ungroup-data-in-a-PivotTable-report-c9d1ddd0-6580-47d1-82bc-c84a5a340725?CorrelationId=fb3c80d9-9c20-4d48-8e6d-c93d943b54c4&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HP010175903), recent versions of Excel can only group numeric data or dates. What's an easy workaround?

My current idea is to do it manually, by creating a new column called "Group," using VLOOKUP to populate it, and then create the PivotTable using that column. But that seems overly much for something that should be handled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that, despite being formatted as numbers, some cells were stored as text (go figure). The solution was to type a 1 in an empty cell, copy that, select the entire column, and use Paste Special --> Multiply.